# Adding extra field to joomla categories

Tags: custom-field, form-fields-types, categories

I need help in adding extra fields to Joomla categories(not article) in my custom component categories and I didnt find any documentation for that. I want to add a time field to categories. I tried to use fieldsattach but it is giving lots of errors. So I started building my own plugin following some joomla docs but i am not able to add extra fields into categories. This is what I tried till now.
I created a plugin xml file named plg_bfquiz_catextras.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<extension version="3.1" type="plugin" group="categories">
    <name>plg_bfquiz_catextras</name>
    <author>Joomla! Project</author>
    <creationDate>January 2021</creationDate>
    <copyright>Copyright (C) 2021 - 2022 . All rights reserved.</copyright>
    <license>GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt</license>
    <authorEmail></authorEmail>
    <authorUrl></authorUrl>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <description>PLG_BFQUIZ_CATEXTRAS_XML_DESCRIPTION</description>
    <files>
        <filename plugin="plg_bfquiz_catextras">plg_bfquiz_catextras.php</filename>
        <folder>forms</folder>
        <filename>index.html</filename>
    </files>
    <languages>
        <language tag="en-GB">en-GB.plg_bfquiz_catextras.ini</language>
        <language tag="en-GB">en-GB.plg_bfquiz_catextras.sys.ini</language>
    </languages>
</extension>
```

Then in plugin plg_bfquiz_catextras.php file

```
<?php
// no direct access
defined ('_JEXEC') or die;
class plgCategoriesBFQuizCatextras extends JPlugin
{
    /**
     * Load the language file on instantiation.
     * Note this is only available in Joomla 3.1 and higher.
     * If you want to support 3.0 series you must override the constructor
     *
     * @var boolean
     * @since <your version>
     */
    protected $autoloadLanguage = true;

    /**
     * Prepare form and add my field.
     *
     * @param   JForm  $form  The form to be altered.
     * @param   mixed  $data  The associated data for the form.
     *
     * @return  boolean
     *
     * @since   <your version>
     */
    function onContentPrepareForm($form, $data)
    {
        $app    = JFactory::getApplication();
        $option = $app->input->get('option');

        switch($option)
        {
            case 'com_bfquiz' :
                if ($app->isClient('administrator'))
                {
                    JForm::addFormPath(__DIR__ . '/forms');
                    $form->loadFile('catxtras', false);
                }

                return true;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
?>
```

And finally I have a forms folder inside which there is a file named catextras.xml with content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form>
    <fields name="params">
        <fieldset name="params" label="PLG_BFQUIZ_CATEXTRAS_FIELDSET_LABEL">
            <field
                name="cat_time"
                type="integer"
                label="PLG_BFQUIZ_CATEXTRAS_TIME"
            />
        </fieldset>
    </fields>
</form>
```

I know I am doing some mistake but I am unable to point it out. Need help from Joomla Experts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many issues with your plugin. First, it doesn't follow the naming convention so your class doesn't get detected at all. See [Creating a Plugin for Joomla](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Creating_a_Plugin_for_Joomla) tutorial for an example of correct class naming.

Assuming your component is using `com_categories` to manage categories, the plugin is using `categories` plugin group but it should be using `content` group instead. The context check is also wrong, it should be using name of the form (`$form->getName()`) instead of current component from input (which would be `com_categories`).
You probably also have a typo. In your post you refer to the form file as `catextras` but in the code it's called `catxtras`.

If your component does use `com_categories` for categories and you want custom fields to be available at all times, you don't even need a plugin. Instead create `category.xml` file in `administrator/components/com_[yourcomponent]/models/forms` and it will be loaded automatically. If you need more control over the form, you can create a helper class `[yourcomponent]HelperCategory` in `administrator/components/com_[yourcomponent]/helpers/category.php` with `onPrepareForm()` method.

Comment: Thanks. Actually i searched for prepareform and came across category model. There i found that category.php file should be there inside my helpers folder. There on i was able to create a custom field. Some 3 hours it took as i could not find any doc by googling.